# Spring: @Transactional with readonly=true not call conn.setReadOnly(true)

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, readonly

I have annotated my service methods with `@Transactional` `readonly=true`.

It since that spring/hibernate not call the setReadonly method of the jdbc connection driver. what can I do?

Because of I will use a master-slave replication and the jdbc pool use the readonly flag on the connection to route the query to the master or to the slaves.

Comment: Are you sure this is the outermost annotation, i.e.read only `@Transactional` is not called from other transactional code?

Comment: When you are using Hibernate as your ORM vendor `@Transactional` only sets the flush mode to `MANUAL`.  I.e. it's "read-only" because they never call `EntityManager.flush()`.  It's a pretty cruel joke if you ask me, but that's what it does.  See [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html) for more information on `@Transactional` pitfalls.

Comment: I have exactly same problem with mysql replication and hibernate.Did you find any solution?

Comment: Setup your own DataSource that is read-only using read-only login credentials and other JDBC driver attributes.  There is no specification requirement for @Transactional to call Connection#setReadOnly() this method is to support read-only SQL cursors (non-updatable ResultSet).  One reason Spring does not do what you want is because most systems use JDBC from a connection pool and the Connection object is shared with another user sequentially.  If you have particular requirement due to replication you should setup another connection pool via another DataSource.

Comment: Hi, maybe this can help: http://khuevu.github.com/2012/10/07/spring-hibernate-mysqlreplication.html

Answer (score 2):

First, you should only set the readOnly flag to the JDBC connection when your PU transaction mode is RESOURCE_LOCAL. If it's JTA, then you must not change that setting, as you will not get the same jdbc connection instance for every jdbc call inside the transaction (JTA - and not Hibernate - will ensure transactional behaviour). When it's LOCAL, Hibernate opens a jdbc connection the first time it requires it, and keeps it for the duration of the transaction.

**1. JPA**

If you're using JPA with Hibernate as the provider, you can add this extra behaviour by 
providing your own implementation of JpaDialect to the EMF definition. When using Hibernate, you will usually inject a HibernateJpaDialect.

JpaDialect interface has a `getJdbcConnection(em, readOnly)` method that returns a handle over the actual JDBC connection. This method is invoked by the JpaTransactionManager when the transaction begins. By default, the HibernateJpaDialect does not change the readOnly setting on the returned connection because of this JTA/RESOURCE_LOCAL duality, but you can do it if you run local transactions only.

Here is an implementation of such a JpaDialect that achieves your goal :

**ResourceLocalReadOnlyAwareHibernateJpaDialect**

```
public class ResourceLocalReadOnlyAwareHibernateJpaDialect extends HibernateJpaDialect {
  public ConnectionHandle getJdbcConnection(EntityManager entityManager, boolean readOnly) throws PersistenceException, SQLException {
    Session session = getSession(entityManager);
    return new HibernateReadOnlyAwareConnectionHandle(session, readOnly);
  }

  // this is similar to spring's HibernateJpaDialect own internal class,
  // except for the readonly flags.
  private static class HibernateReadOnlyAwareConnectionHandleimplements ConnectionHandle {
    private final Session session;
    private final boolean readOnly;
    private static volatile Method connectionMethod;

    public HibernateConnectionHandle(Session session, boolean readOnly) {
      this.session = session;
      this.readOnly = readOnly;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
      try {
        if (connectionMethod == null) {
          // reflective lookup to bridge between Hibernate 3.x and 4.x
          connectionMethod = this.session.getClass().getMethod("connection");
        }
        Connection con = (Connection) ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(connectionMethod, this.session);
        con.setReadOnly(this.readOnly);
        return con;
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find connection() method on Hibernate session", ex);
      }
    }

    public void releaseConnection(Connection con) {   // #1
      con.setReadOnly(false);
      JdbcUtils.closeConnection(con);
    }
  }

}
```

Note #1 : Resets the readOnly flag to false prior closing the connection (actually not a real `connection.close()` call, but just releasing the connection to the pool). Not quite sure what triggers this method call, but it looks legitimate to reset the readOnly flag in the same class as where it was changed.

**2. Pure Hibernate**

First, ensure `HibernateTransactionManager.prepareConnection` remains true.

Then, I'm not sure what to do. You have to debug into Spring's `HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession()` : if the method returns true, connection.setReadOnly() will be invoked, thus all fine.

If not, you can either change Hibernate's connectionReleaseMode setting to ON_CLOSE (hibernate property `hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session=true`, which was the default before Hibernate 3.1), or overwrite `HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession()` in order to always return true (which is considered safe in regards to HibernateTransactionManager comments). Both are "advanced tuning", but should be safe AFAIK. Actually, I think that `HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession()` should be changed to return true for both ON_CLOSE **and** AFTER_TRANSACTION release modes : in regard to HibernateTransactionManager, cleanup happens anyway after transaction completion, thus not altering Hibernate behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions worth investigating are mentioned here: http://www.dragishak.com/?p=307

1. Using AOP to set the JDBC connection to readOnly. This is the focus of the blog post.
2. Using hooks in the connection pool to choose a different connection based on `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()`. This varies based on which connection pool implementation you're using (e.g. BoneCP, c3p0, not sure if it's supported in DBCP yet). See the comments section of the link above.